# How can I set an initial position (xyz) for a link that is connected via a floating joint in URDF?

Tags: ros, urdf

I wish to connect a child link in a predefined initial position relative to another parent link, via a floating joint.

When I try to do it with the origin tag of the joint it doesn't affect at all!

```
 <link name="world" />

 <link name="test">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="1.0 0.4 0.1" />
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
        </visual>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="10"/>
            <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
          </inertial>
          
    </link>

    <joint name="test_joint" type="floating">
        <parent link="world" />
        <child link="test" />

        <!-- This line doesn't affect anything -->
        <origin xyz="0 0 1" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </joint>
```